# How to execute a function every 1 minute

Tags: python, time, mqtt, schedule, broker

I am running a Python script that is connected to an mqtt gateway.

I am attaching a part of the code.
In the script, I have an `on_message` function which gets the data from the mqtt topic. So while running, I need to call another function every 1 minute.
I tried using `schedule.every(1).minutes.do(func)`
but the problem is while running through the if and elif loop, it does not detect how much time it takes and does not run the `schedule.every(1).miutes.do(func)`

```
def (func):
   #do something

def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
   global buffer1
   global buffer2
     
   if msg.topic == "test/topic":
       buffer1.append(msg.payload)
       print("buffer1",buffer1)
    
   elif msg.topic == "test/topic2":
       buffer2.append(msg.payload)
       print("buffer2",buffer2)
   schedule.every(1).minutes.do(func)
```

Comment: The on_message() func is only called when an MQTT message arrives, so your schedule.every(1) call only happens the first time an MQTT message is received by the client.  Put that outside of the on_message() func, if you truely want a func called every minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the threading modules in python to execute a function every 1 minute.

```
import threading

def my_function():
    # put your code here
    print("Function called every minute")

def run_function():
    thread = threading.Timer(60.0, run_function) # 60 seconds = 1 minute
    thread.start()
    my_function()

run_function() # start the timer
```

In this example, `my_function()` is the function you want to execute every minute. `run_function()` is a recursive function that starts a timer to execute `my_function()` after 60 seconds. The timer is restarted after every execution of `my_function()`, so it runs indefinitely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have a concern.
As you see in my script ,i need to run the on_message first and when it is almost 1 minute of running it I need to call another function .Now when I optimize the code by adding your input .I have added the function call for the run_function()  just after the on_message() call function. So when I run it ,it just calls the run_function() and not the on_message(). @sanaf

Comment: you have to specify the function that you want to run in the threading.Timer function. here in this example it will run my_function every 1 minute

so, just replace the my_function with on_message inside the run_function.